# Unable to install Search Guard plugin for Elasticsearch-5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

Due to the restrictions, I was not allowed to install any packages from internet. So, This command is not useful for me inorder to install [search-guard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard).

```
 bin/elasticsearch-plugin install -b com.floragunn:search-guard-ssl:<version>
```

However, I am able to install Search Guard successfully on a different network by running the above command.

Because of this reason, I tried installing Search Guard from tar.gz or zip file by the below command as per [documentation](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-ssl-docs/blob/master/installation.md).

```
 /usr/share/elasticsearch# bin/elasticsearch-plugin install     file:///home/xxxx/xxxx/search-guard-5-5.2.0-10-sgadmin-standalone.zip
```

This one is failing with the below error.

```
 -> Downloading file:///home/xxx/xxxx/search-guard-5-5.2.0-10-  sgadmin-standalone.zip
 [=================================================] 100%   
 ERROR: `elasticsearch` directory is missing in the plugin zip
```

I downloaded zip/tar.gz from [this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/floragunn/search-guard-5/5.2.0-10/) maven repository of search gaurd.

Is anyone also facing the same issue. If not, kindly help in solving this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download this file from maven to /home/xxxx:
       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/floragunn/search-guard-5/5.2.0-11/search-guard-5-5.2.0-11.zip

Install it:

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install -b file:///home/xxxx/search-guard-5-5.2.0-11.zip
```

Other releases are available here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/floragunn/